# Use jshint inside VIM in sync with Yeoman's jshint task

Tags: vim, jshint, yeoman

I am using VIM as my text editor and Yeoman to help me with my webapp development workflow.

I am already using [vim-jshint](http://sleistner.github.com/vim-jshint) to help me lint my javascript files from within VIM and I would like to use it in sync with my Yeoman setup.

My problem is that every time I run `grunt`, the `jshint` task founds lots of errors that vim-jshint couldn't find.

I am aware vim-jshint looks for a .jshintrc file in two possible paths: the HOME path and the current working directory but, in its current state of development, vim-jshint seems to be unable to find the .jshintrc that Yeoman uses, which is located in the base directory of the webapp.

Has any of you found a solution or workaround for this?

Please, switching to Sublime Text is not an option.

Comment: If I read it correctly, the script is trying to load a `.jshintrc` file located in Vim's "current working directory". Switching to that directory with `:cd /path/to/project` should solve your problem.

Comment: @romainl I should have clarified that I had already tried that and it didn't work. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Do you mean that yeoman's `.jshintrc` is not recognised when you run the jshint plugin from the root of your project?

Comment: All the messages I am getting from `grunt jshint` that are not reported by `vim-jshint` are either `Missing space after ...` or `Unexpected space after...`. Therefore it may not be a jshintrc-related issue but, instead, something related to jshint's `white` option that seems to be working in two different ways. I will post anything I can find here.

Comment: I did some research and it seems jshint's `white` option is somewhat deprecated. So I set it to `false` and now I am getting no errors from `grunt jshint` at all. However, I still get some errors from vim-jshint. In my opinion, the only reasonable solution to this would be to have the same yeoman-installed jshint implementation, executed from inside Vim. Do you believe this is doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! I was using the wrong vim-jshint plugin.

I should have used the one that's listed in JSHint's site from the beginning, but somehow I was misled to the wrong plugins. Stupid me.

Finally, having [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) installed, I just had to copy and paste this:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/walm/jshint.vim
```

As stated in its own github README file, *This plugin is a front for the jshint NodeJS cli module* which ensures that running `:JSHint` inside VIM will always report the same errors as grunt's `jshint` task. At least if you run VIM from the same folder where JSHint's options file (`.jshintrc`) is located.